# Connnect to PostGIS db using QGIS - when not on localhost

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql

I"m just getting started with PostgreSQL/PostGIS db (v9.2) and I'm wanting to connect to db while not on the localhost using QGIS.  I've been able to connect successfully on localhost, however I'm not sure what I need to do to make this non localhost connection.  I'm able to ping the db server from my desktop.

In pgAdmin within the db properties I defined the following privileges:

[image]

Then in QGIS here are my connection settings (using postgres username/password, but logged in as my domain user):

[image]

I've tried searching the web for this, however all the hits are just coming up with examples of how to connect on localhost.  I'm thinking maybe I have to add my domain info as user login?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HOST should be the IP of the POSTGIS/Postgres Location

on Windows you can do `ipconfig` to get the v4 ip something like 192.0.168.101

You need to allow connections to this server in postgres **pg_hba.conf**

see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html

firewalls also need to be adjusted to accommodate successful connections.

You can use the Trust switch

```
host    all         all         192.168.0.101/32        trust
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406025/no-pg-hba-conf-entry-for-host

Answer (score 2):

The defaults for Postgres don't allow remote connections.  To allow remote connections you'll need to modify the pg_hba.conf and postgresql.conf files on your sever.

Here's a quick how to on which settings need to be changed in which config files:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/postgres-allow-remote-access-tcp-connection.html

Comment: For my 9.2 version, there are two pg_hba.conf files one in \9.2\data and in \9.2\share.  Do I edit both, or just one of these files?

Comment: the file in \data should be the file Postgres is reading so edit that one.

Answer (score 2):

First, edit postgresql.conf file so that the server will listen to any address:

1. In pgAdmin (after connected to your server as postgres or any super user): select menu 'Tools -> Server Configuration -> postgresql.conf'
2. Double click on 'listen_addresses' line and change 'value' to '*'[image]
3. Press the 'Save' button [image], then 'Reload Server to apply configuration changes' [image]
4. Close the Backend Configuration Editor window.

Edit pg_hba.conf file to allow postgres to connect to your databases.

1. In pgAdmin select menu 'Tools -> Server Configuration -> pg_hba.conf'
2. Create a new line or modify an existing line so that its content like the following highlighted (orange) line:[image]With this line, user postgres can connect to any database (all) from any ip address (0.0.0.0/0) with md5 method (enter username and password).
3. Save, Reload and close the window.

Now you can connect to your database from Qgis like you've done in your question.