# QGIS Server does not publish PostGIS, Oracle or SQLITE Layer

Tags: qgis-server

I want to publish a Postgis Layer which is defined in a QGIS Project with the QGIS Server. The capabilities document of the QGIS Server does not include the layer description of the  Layer. If i try this for example with a local shp Layer it will work. Is there a solution about this.

My Version of QGIS is 2.6 for Windows 64 bit and i installed the QGIS Server over the OSGEO setup on the same system.

The REQUEST=GetMap return a blank image

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions in this post?
[Connect to PosGIS db using QGIS when not on localhost][1]


  [1]: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58446/connnect-to-postgis-db-using-qgis-when-not-on-localhost

Comment: Yes i tried it. I can add PostGIS layer in the desktop version , but not over the server.